# Dependent field not refreshing after saving changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view that is displaying a StartDate and an EndDate, and a readonly field showing the number of days between the two dates.  All these fields are bound to my model with the standard @Html.EditorFor() methods in the razor view definition.  When I change one of the dates and click Save, the

```
[HttpPost]
ViewResult Edit([modeltype] editedModel){
 ... }
```

method calculates and sets a new value for the calculated field before saving the new dates and calculated value to the database, and then returns the View with the updated model.  The problem I have is that the view does not show the new calculated value (instead it shows the original calculated value as per the initial page load).  Until I navigate away from and back to that view - then it shows the calculated value correctly.  Any idea what I'm missing?  Is the browser perhaps showing a cached version of the page after my HttpPost?  If so, can I disable that behavior?

Comment: What does the Action return? My first guess is that your not returning an updated version of the model to the view after the database update.

Comment: The last line of the Edit method is Return View(editedModel);  and using a breakpoint (and Debug.Writeline) I have confirmed that on that line, "editedModel" definitely contains the correctly calculated value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Html helpers prefers the `ModelStateCollection` over the actual `Model`. This means they will display the posted values instead of the ones you've update in the controller.

So if you want to return the same model that you got in your action and you have changed some of the values you need to clear the `ModelState` before returning your model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Edit(MyModel editedModel)
{

   //set some properties on editedModel

   ModelState.Clear();
   return View(editedModel);
}
```

Comment: This is interesting, I've never done this but also never had this problem.

Comment: This will prevent any validation from showing if you have any unfortunately

Comment: @CodeBlend that is true. However you don't need to clear the whole modelstate. It is usually enough to remove only the changed properties with `ModelState.Remove("PropertyNameWhatChangedInController")`